# Determining if a folder is shared in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, windows

Is there a way through the .net framework to determine if a folder is shared or not?

Neither Diretory, DirectoryInfo or FileAttributes seem to have any corresponding field.

One thing I forgot to mention was that I want to be checking for network shares.  But I'll investigate the WMI stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use WMI Win32_Share.
Take a look at:

http://www.gamedev.net/community/forums/topic.asp?topic_id=408923

Shows a sample for querying, creating and deleting shared folders.

Comment: can you tell me how to check the shared folder in local pc exist.I need to test it from pocket pc(using .net compact framework),refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25710537/check-shared-path-is-available-in-pc

Answer (score 10):

You can get a list of all the shared folders using the WMI Win32_Share and see if the folder you're looking for is between them. Here's a snippet that might help you with this:

```
public static List<string> GetSharedFolders()
{

  List<string> sharedFolders = new List<string>();

  // Object to query the WMI Win32_Share API for shared files...

  ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("select * from win32_share");

  ManagementBaseObject outParams;

  ManagementClass mc = new ManagementClass("Win32_Share"); //for local shares

  foreach (ManagementObject share in searcher.Get()){

  string type = share["Type"].ToString();

  if (type == "0") // 0 = DiskDrive (1 = Print Queue, 2 = Device, 3 = IPH)
  {
    string name = share["Name"].ToString(); //getting share name

    string path = share["Path"].ToString(); //getting share path

    string caption = share["Caption"].ToString(); //getting share description

    sharedFolders.Add(path);
  }

  }

  return sharedFolders;

}
```

Please note that I brutally copy-pasted from this [link](http://bytes.com/forum/thread624242.html) on bytes

Comment: can you tell me how to check the shared folder in local pc exist.I need to test it from pocket pc(using .net compact framework),refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25710537/check-shared-path-is-available-in-pc

Answer (score 4):

One more way to skin this cat is to use powershell (if you have it installed) to invoke the wmi call, include a reference to System.Management.Automation, it will most likley be in \program files\reference assemblies\microsoft\windowspowershell

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Runspace rs = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
  rs.Open();
  Pipeline pl = rs.CreatePipeline();
  pl.Commands.AddScript("get-wmiobject win32_share");

  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  Collection<PSObject> list = pl.Invoke();
  rs.Close();
  foreach (PSObject obj in list)
  {
    string name = obj.Properties["Name"].Value as string;
    string path = obj.Properties["Path"].Value as string;
    string desc = obj.Properties["Description"].Value as string;

    sb.AppendLine(string.Format("{0}{1}{2}",name, path, desc));
  }
  // do something with the results...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using WMI and doing a `SELECT * FROM Win32_ShareToDirectory` query.