# how to make sure the share path exist, if not, return false in time

Tags: c#

I want to know whether the share path exist,maybe the **Directory.Exists(string path)** is not a good method due to wasting about 20 seconds when return false. Is there a way to return "true or false" whether the share path exist **in time**(for example. 1 or 2 second)

Answer (score 1):

You need to run `Directory.Exists` in a separate thread and implement the timeout yourself.

Call [`Thread.Join(TimeSpan ts)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/23f7b1ct.aspx) with your timeout.

Answer (score 0):

Try method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136539/determining-if-a-folder-is-shared-in-net) (it rely on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394435(VS.85).aspx)

Also, to decrease response time you can do some check prior really checks share.

BTW, why so weird response time? Do you make check over slow Internet connection (VPN) or your network so slow?

Also you can try [this method](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/pinvokeaddshare.aspx?msg=3485406) but it requires PInvoke (here [details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb525385(VS.85).aspx)), so first method is preferable.

And you can check is there network available via

```
System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable()
```

before do any further checks or maybe some more network checks (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ew4thdx.aspx)) e.g. ping host to check its availability and after all check for network share.

If you want to do it in background than you can follow Albin Sunnanbo's advice