# For loop in batch

Tags: loops, batch-file, for-loop

I execuet the below batch to get my script "mvn.bat" to execute on all the folders under a directory.
As you see the for loop considers "*" as input and this all folders are considered for execution.

```
FOR /D %%G in ("*") DO (
    D:\maven\bin\mvn.bat jcli:deploy -Dlist.dir="./%%G" -Denv.name=Server1 -Dint.service=Server service
)
```

I now wanted the script to ignore folders that ends with Shared (condition "*Shared"), i tried several ways putting if loop to filter and etc,, but nothing worked out, any sugeestion or solution will be helpful..

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to tell what you are really asking but I think you cannot do that in a DOS batch script but you can do that in C# or Powershell possibly.  Your clue can be [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136539/determining-if-a-folder-is-shared-in-net) ?

Comment: I think i miscommunicated, I wanted the loop to exclue folders with the name '*shared' and they are not really a shared folders