# How to know a new folder is created in a particular folder

Tags: c#, windows, directory, desktop-application

I am developing a desktop application in C#.
I have programmatically created a folder(say ABC) inside the Main folder in C drive in Windows.
I want to know whether an user has created any new folder(by simply right clicking and creating new folder) inside ABC.
If the user has created a new folder then I need to get the details of that folder like folder name and privacy too.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have a look at the [System.IO.FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

Comment: When you say *"user has created any new folder"* it is not entirely clear what *"new"* means. *"New"* relative to what event?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the subdirectories of a folder (in your example, the folder "ABC") as an array of strings by calling the method `GetDirectories`:

```
string[] subdirs = Directory.GetDirectories(@"C:\ABC");
```

Then, if you'd like, you can iterate through all of them:

```
foreach (string dir in subdirs)
    //dir is a path to a subdirectory
```

Don't forget the `using` statement!

```
using System.IO;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [DirectoryInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo%28VS.80%29.aspx) to get the list of subfolder

```
DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\ABC");
DirectoryInfo[] subFolders = dirInfo.GetDirectories();
```

I'm not sure what you mean by *privacy*...

Comment: By the term Privacy I meant whether the folder is private or shared to other users also.
If I have many folders like ABC and also subfolders in ABC then how can I give the folder path?

Comment: @abi_anarchy95 read here about shared folders: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/136539/determining-if-a-folder-is-shared-in-net